# Should vertices be preserved across frames

Tags: xna, monogame

I have read an article that guides you through writing your own SpriteBatch and I've noticed that all the vertices and indices are destroyed and recreated each frame. Isn't that wasteful? Wouldn't it be better if all of the data was permanently stored in the SpriteBatch and a way to manipulate them was added? Could someone please tell me the cons of doing it like that?

Thanks for any opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a game that literally always has the same triangles (or the like) rendered on every frame, and just needs to tweak the coordinates, then it may be worthwhile to customize your own SpriteBatch to recognize that.  If you sometimes show/hide stuff, it might get messy and complicated.  Only way to find out the possible benefit is to profile your code and find where the meaningful bottlenecks are.

Since SpriteBatch deals in structs and pre-allocated lists and arrays, there shouldn't be any wastefulness of memory allocation, so it just becomes a question of whether you can avoid re-assigning all those values, and (if this applies to you) avoid performing the z-order sort.

I myself use a customized SpriteBatch, and based on profiling, I can see that the z-order sort step is the primary bottleneck in my SpriteBatch drawing call stack.  However, my frame rates are already OK enough on my wimpiest target platforms.  So at least at this point, I have no reason to attempt further optimization there.  Furthermore, my app has a bigger need for optimization of my physics and segregating my drawables by their orthogonal updating characteristics to avoid unnecessary update work.

Your results may vary. Good luck!